# How to display hg status with full paths instead of relative ones?

Tags: mercurial

I want to run `hg status` and display the changed files with full path?

Why? because I want to display changes to 3 different repositories and by default hg displays them relative to the repository root.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing in the [`hg status` man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#status) suggests Mercurial directly supports that.

How about a bit of `sed` magic?

```
$ pwd
/var/www/mysite

$ hg st
A static/logo.png
M static/style.css
? temp.txt

$ hg st | sed -e "s~^\(.\) ~\1 ${PWD}/~g"
A /var/www/mysite/static/logo.png
M /var/www/mysite/static/style.css
? /var/www/mysite/temp.txt
```

You can use shell aliases (described in [the manual](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias)) to make Mercurial do this instead of the regular `hg st`.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Helgi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686284) here's a variation using PowerShell:

```
hg status | % { $_ -replace '^([^ ]+ )(.+)$', ('$1' + $(Get-Location) + '\$2') }
```